# How to achieve the effect being the same as using glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.99f)?

Tags: opengl

I have a png image used as texture, part of which is transparent since the alpha is 0. Now it seems that "glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.99f)" and "glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)" is no longer used. I'm thinking about using Blending. But how to achieve that?

In addition, can anyone explain to me how the function

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
```

works? What's the source scale factor & destination scale factor and how they are used?

Comment: The default blend equation is additive, so that blend function works out to `Src.rgb * Src.rgb  +  Dst.rgb * 0` (where `Src` is the incoming color and `Dst` is the color already in the framebuffer). I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish here? Where did that blend function come from?

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman  This is just an example (probably doesn't make any sense), since I don't understand how the two parameters work here. What you said make sense to me. So if I change it to glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE), will the result be like this: Src.a * Src.rgb + Dst.rgb * 1 ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha function discards fragments based on their alpha. It's part of the fixed pipeline. In the programmable pipeline you'd just compare your alpha as appropriate and call `discard` if necessary. Alternatively, if you prefer and your blend mode is suitable, just push the alpha down to `0.0`.

If you're not using the programmable pipeline then you should use `glAlphaFunc` — you're explicitly writing things the old fashioned way.

`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ZERO)` effectively uses the source pixel's R, G, B, A, as the source scaling factors and 0 as the destination scaling factors. So the output pixel will be a function of the input only and each channel will be squared.